# starting chrome via WebDriver session wont use default profile - windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, python, cmd.exe

I came from this [GitHub](https://github.com/Second-Hand-Friends/kleinanzeigen-bot) but there are mainly linux prof. When I run the program via cmd chrome is opened but without any default profiles:
[chrome via program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UKwm.png)

When I run chrome direct via cmd with `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` and `--profile-directory=Default` I see this
[chrome via cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1hbj.png)

So I try to figure out with my noob knowledge and try and fail error, why is this a different instance.

This is the LOG

```
[INFO] Creating WebDriver session...
[INFO] Using Browser: GOOGLE-CHROME 120.0.6099.225 [C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe]
[INFO]  -> Browser Profile Name: Default
[INFO]  -> Custom chrome argument: --profile-directory='Default'
[INFO]  -> Custom chrome argument: --remote-debugging-port=9222
[INFO]  -> Chrome binary location: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
[INFO] New WebDriver session is: e79a1a8359490xxxxxxxxx
```

This [issue](https://github.com/Second-Hand-Friends/kleinanzeigen-bot/issues/219) is already reported, since 10/2023 :-(

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the two profile directories. I suspect I know what’s going on

Comment: @Ramhound this location? https://i.ibb.co/9tCPWWt/chrome-JPG.jpg

Comment: Yeah, you have two default profiles, because the way your launching Chrome is causing the profile to be in the application folder. I doubt that’s what you mean to do.

Comment: @Ramhound so what do you suggest? A clean install?

Comment: Why are you starting Chrome from two different locations and attempting to use the same user profile? Is there two user profiles for Default one in Program Files and another in “C:\Users\(Username)\AppData\Local\” within the Chrome directory?